# Rails 5: How to restrict collection creation from has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to know how to restrict collection create! method from an specific association.

I have these models:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :company_users
     has_many :companies, through: :company_users
  end
  class CompanyUser < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :company
     validates :user, :company, presence: true
  end
  class Company < ApplicationRecord   
     has_many :company_users
     has_many :users, through: :company_users
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  end
```

I need to restrict collection create! method like this:

```
User.first.companies.create! name: "Company", address: "Address" # <-- want to raise an exception

Company.first.users.create! email: "e@mail.com", password: "1234", password_confirmation: "1234" # <-- want NOT to raise an exception
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: override create method of active_record in your specific model and add your custom code along with existing code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but that's what I don't know how to do